# BeautifulSoup - Find <h1> <h2> & <h3> tags elements which is placed above <a> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I scrape the following structure to only get `h1`, `h2` & `h3` elements above `<a>` tag

I would like to get all `<a>` tag heading which are placed above by targeting the `<a>` tag in beautiful soup.

HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Heading H1</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <a href="#">Button</a>

    <hr>

    <h2>Heading H2</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Button</a>
    </p>

    <hr>

    <h3>Heading H3</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Button</a>
    </p>
    
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

My Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/test.html'
result = requests.get(website)
content = result.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text)
# print(soup.prettify())

href_tags = ["a"]
for tags in soup.find_all(href_tags):
    print(tags.name + ' -> ' + tags.text.strip())
```

Tried with above code it's displaying `<a>` tag text only. I would also like to get the `<h1>`, `<h2>` & `<h3>` tags which are placed above the `<a>` tag.

Comment: What *exactly* is the expected result?

Comment: I would like to get all <a> tag heading which placed above by targeting the <a> tag in beautiful soup.

Comment: Sorry, but that is too vague. In your snippet you printed out `<a>` tags' `.name` and `.text`. Do you want to do the same with `<h1>`, `<h2>` and `<h3>`? Or something else? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of getting that information:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Heading H1</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <a href="#">Button</a>

    <hr>

    <h2>Heading H2</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Button</a>
    </p>

    <hr>

    <h3>Heading H3</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Button</a>
    </p>
    
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
'''
big_list = []
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('a'):
    link_text = link.get_text(strip=True)
    link_url = link.get('href')
    previous_header = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in link.find_all_previous() if x.name in ['h1', 'h2', 'h3']][0]
    big_list.append((link_text, link_url, previous_header))
df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns=['link_text', 'link_url', 'previous_header_text'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    link_text   link_url    previous_header_text
0   Button  #   Heading H1
1   Button  #   Heading H2
2   Button  #   Heading H3
```

See BeautifulSoup documentation [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).